# The game is slower on powerful devices. I am use delta

Tags: java, libgdx

Why android game slowest on the most powerfull devices, but on standard devices game is normal, and on substandard devices game is fast (I mean movement in game).

I am try multiply game objects speed by delta and try to limit FPS to 60f/s.

```
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        stage.act(Math.min(delta, 1 / 61f)); // At now i try with limit
        stage.draw();
        if (!isPaused && isAlive()) {
            if (Gdx.input.getPressure() > 0) balloon.setDir(true);
            else balloon.setDir(false);
            updateLogic(Math.min(delta, 1 / 61f));
        }

/// Its render.

if (getUser().getCurrentLocation().isPaused()) return;
        float tempSpeed = speed * delta;

// Its velocity calculation;
```

Comment: "powerful" and "standard" are vague terms.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to multiply speed by delta time and use that as your game speed. Multiplying speed by delta time gives you the amount of displacement for the current frame. What are you using tempSpeed for?

Comment: I mean velocity objects in game, speed of their shift

Answer (score 0):

The problem with variable movement speed on different devices may be caused by `Math.min()`.

Let's talk about three different scenarios:

1. Slow device: 30 FPS / render calls, avg. delta 0.033 s

   ```
   Math.min(0.033, 0.016) == 0.016
   ```
2. Normal device: 60 FPS / render calls, avg. delta 0.017 s

   ```
   Math.min(0.017, 0.016) == 0.016
   ```
3. Fast device: 120 FPS / render calls, avg. delta 0.008 s

   ```
   Math.min(0.008, 0.016) == 0.008
   ```

You can see that the delta time on slow devices after calling `Math.min()` is the same as on normal devices, causing the speed to be lower on slow devices.

If you want to limit the FPS, you should use `Thread.sleep()` or similar solutions, not `Math.min()` in your render loop. Your solution doesn't limit the FPS, it only modifies the update speed.

[This post at libGDX forum](https://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=30014#p30014) describes a solution how to limit the FPS.